# How can I set priority on constraints in Swift?

Tags: swift, constraints

I've been struggling to make priority on constraints work programmatically in Swift.

My goal is to have the `meetingFormView` no more than 300 wide. Using IB I would give the width constraint a lower priority and give a higher priority to the "lessThanOrEqualToConstant". But I can't get it to work.

I've tried this:

```
meetingFormView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

let constraintWidth = NSLayoutConstraint(
        item: meetingFormView,
        attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.width,
        relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal,
        toItem: startView,
        attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.width,
        multiplier: 1,
        constant: 0)
constraintWidth.priority = .defaultHigh

NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    meetingFormView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 20),
    meetingFormView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 170),
    meetingFormView.widthAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualToConstant: 300),
    meetingFormView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
    constraintWidth
])
```

Comment: I work only with "anchor" constraints instead of this style (I honestly can't recall the correct name for it) but a constraint is a constraint, and what I see looks pretty good. That said, you seek in terms of IB (something I also rarely use but can) and I see nothing of an `IBOutlet` *constraint* in your code. Like objects (for instance `meetingFormView`) you can make a *constraint* declared in IB available to change in code by declaring it as an `IBOutlet`. Are you doing that?

Comment: Yes - elsewhere there's an IBOutlet for the meetingFormView. I've mixed the two constraint types since it seems that the object.anchor.constraint-notation doesn't support priority??

Comment: I prefaced my comment by basically saying my usage of constraints is (a) in code and (b) with anchors. (I *have* used IB, set priorities, and made IBOutlets - just not anything with production code.) When I set priorities for an anchor-based constraint - again, in code - it seems to take *two* lines of code to set up (and of course one to change)... (1) create the "named" constraint, as in `widthAnchor` with a constant and/or multiplier if needed, and (2) set `isActive = true`. If I combine them? Xcode seems to not recognize the type of the variable, which is `NSLayoutConstraint`.

Comment: Followup comment.   Once I do that (and Xcode recognizes that the type is `NSLayoutConstraint`) I have no problem setting priorities. I'll post code, maybe it'll help you.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It actually seems to take *three* lines of code to set up a prioritized "anchor-based" constraint in code:

```
let widthConstraint = meetingFormView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 170)
widthConstraint.priority = UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 500)
widthConstraint.isActive = true
```

It seems like if I try to set `isActive` with the `let` declare Xcode (maybe Swift?) doesn't recognize that the type is `NSLayoutConstraint`. And using `UILayoutPriority(rawValue:)` seems to be the best (only?) way to set priorities.

While this answer doesn't conform *exactly* with what you are doing, I believe it will work with IB. Just replace the `let` with creating an `IBOutlet` and there should be no need for the `isActive` line.

Obviously, to *change* the priority later in code you just need:

```
widthConstraint.priority = UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 750)
```

Answer (score 6):

You can write a small extension like this:

```
extension NSLayoutConstraint
{
    func withPriority(_ priority: Float) -> NSLayoutConstraint
    {
        self.priority = UILayoutPriority(priority)
        return self
    }
}
```

then use it like this:

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    ...
    meetingFormView.widthAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualToConstant: 300).withPriority(500),
    ...
])
```