# Programmatically set constraint priority

Tags: swift, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have a requirement to recreate a `.xib` based layout programmatically.

I have largely been able to achieve this, however, cannot set the priority of one of my anchors.

The setting I am trying to reproduce in code is:

[image: xib constraints]

I thought I could set it using `setContentHuggingPriority(.init(999), for: .vertical)` but this had no effect.

How can I target this property in code?

Comment: Sorry, is your view(s) and layout programmatic, or a mix of both?

Comment: It was programmatic with an included `.xib` file, it has been requested that we use no xibs in our project so I am recreating the xibbed layout in code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set priority on constraints in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53050685/set-priority-on-constraints-in-swift)

Answer (score 27):

You should use a priority lower than 1000, so 999 will be perfect.

```
let constraint = firstView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: secondView.widthAnchor)
constraint.priority = UILayoutPriority(999)
constraint.isActive = true
```

**Update**

You can also use `defaultLow` instead of specifying the raw value

```
constraint.priority = .defaultLow
```

Comment: Wouldn’t it be better to suggest `UILayoutPriority(999)` since that’s the priority in the question?

Comment: It's been 6 months since my answer in the dup question was accepted, so I may be wrong here - but my memory tells me that `UILayoutPriority(999)` doesn't work anymore. It needs to be `UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 999)`. Again, I could be wrong.

Comment: @dfd Both initializers seem to exist. [`init(_ rawValue: Float)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilayoutpriority/2897306-init) and [`init(rawValue: Float)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilayoutpriority/2897435-init).

Answer (score 2):

I know it's super late, but here if it helps someone. So you will need 2 constraints if you want to play with priority.

```
private var _constraintToManageHQ:NSLayoutConstraint?
_constraintToManageHQ = _viewHBar1.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: _lblAddress.bottomAnchor, constant: 14.0)
_constraintToManageHQ!.isActive = true
_constraintToManageHQ!.priority = UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 995)
```

the other constraint with default 1000 priority

```
_viewHBar1.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: _containerHeadQuater.bottomAnchor, constant: 14.0).isActive = true
```

and once 
`_containerHeadQuater.removeFromSuperview()` is removed from superview, your `_constraintToManageHQ` with lower priority kicks in and keeps the UI stable.